# Multidimensional Array Foreach Tree

Tags: php, arrays

I trying to take an array and make a new multidimensional with parent and childs. I'm able to get close i think, but don't look right still.

```
$value->menu_item_parent //Contains the parent value that can be used for key
```

What I'm I missing?

```
$the_mega = array();
foreach ($menuitems as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->menu_item_parent=='0') {
        $the_mega["parents"][]=$value->title;
    }else{
        $the_mega[$value->title]["childs"]=$value->title;
    }       
}
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($the_mega);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

```
 Array
(
    [parents] => Array
        (
            [0] => Parent 1
            [1] => Parent 2
        )

    [Child 1] => Array
        (
            [childs] => Child 1
        )

    [Child 2] => Array
        (
            [childs] => Child 2
        )

    [Child 3] => Array
        (
            [childs] => Child 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you post a var_dump or print_r of `$menu_items`?

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on the goal. Do you think you could post a sample output of what you would *like* the end array to look like?

Comment: What exactly dou want to achieve? Should Child1/2 both be elements of [0]?

Comment: @MBaas Yes, #menuitems array is a flat array which has menu_item_parent which value has it's parent. I'm trying to make one single array with parent and childs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$the_mega = array();
foreach ($menuitems as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->menu_item_parent=='0') {
        $the_mega[$key]['parents'][]=$value->title;
    }else{
        $the_mega[$value->title]['childs'][]=$value->title;
    }       
}
```

Comment: how can the childs be an array of each parent?